# Css inner border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

jsfiddle.net/warpoluido/JkDhN/175/  - here is what I tried so far.

I'm trying to make the green part a little higher than the blue(or whatever color this is) one, like the image.

it has to be responsive

```
<div class="modulo-titulopagina_verde">
<header class="modulo-titulopagina">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-12 col-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <h1><span>{galeria}</span> {Mod_TituloTitulo}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--BEGIN MOD_TITULO_SUBTITULO -->
        <!-- END MOD_TITULO_SUBTITULO -->
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.modulo-titulopagina {
    position:relative;
    background: #166270; /* Old browsers */
    height: 65px;
    width:33%;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomtop: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
}

.modulo-titulopagina_verde {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #72C267;
    height: 65px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.modulo-titulopagina h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'myriadpro-light';
    font-size: 34px;
    margin: -10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code within the question as you were told when you added that JSFiddle link.

Comment: your demo looks fairly OK, you can just need to tweak it a little.

Comment: Just change the width of the blue bar? `.modulo-titulopagina`

Comment: @KingKing but if I do so, it will look like this http://jsfiddle.net/warpoluido/JkDhN/175/

Comment: You need to reduce the width amount of the blue bar that should do the trick.

Comment: I've edited the question, it's not the width of the green bar that I want to change it's is its height, without affecting the blue bar

Comment: Said it before and I will say it again...two background images would be so much easier and heck of a lot less unnecessary HTML. sometimes an image is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this suit you :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/JkDhN/178/)**

CSS I added (I also set `.modulo-titulopagina_verde {height:65px;}`) :

```
.modulo-titulopagina_verde:after{
    content:'';
    background:inherit;
    height:10px;
    display:block;
    width:47%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

PS : I couldn't resist, flowers are much more peacefull than knifes...

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of titulopagina to something less than 50%. the 30% looks like it solved your problem. Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5V64/)

```
.modulo-titulopagina {

    position:relative;
    background: #166270; /* Old browsers */

    height: 65px;
    width:30%;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomtop: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;


}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/warpoluido/JkDhN/175/ I need to add 10px height to the green part without affect the blue one

Comment: `.modulo-titulopagina_verde {

    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #72C267;
    height: 95px;}`
Change it in modulo_titulopagina verde

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying

```
.modulo-titulopagina { width: ... }
```

to something smaller than 53%.

With 30% it will look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/alejandronanez/AtqQU/1/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/warpoluido/JkDhN/175 I need to add 10px height to the green part without affect the blue one